# Restoring site using .sql backup import

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, backup, restore

I'm unable to restore my site database and need help figuring out why. The Wordpress site is on my local computer.

Here's what I did:
• Exported the backup file in a zip format
• Made updates to plugins through Wordpress platform
• Site crashed from bad update; tried to delete that plugin and made things worse
• Decided to restore backup; tried importing through phpmyadmin; came back with errors
• Dropped all the tables from that database
• Unzipped by backup file; commented out "create database" line
• Tried importing again and came up with the following errors:
   #1007 - Can't create database 'Wordpress'; database exists

I've built several websites locally in the past so yes, there's already another database called Wordpress. I'm not sure how to delete them besides dropping the tables.

I'm losing hope that I'll ever be able to restore this site.

Any insight?

Comment: There must still be a `CREATE DATABASE` command in your sql backup. You'll have to edit it to create a database by another name rather than one you already have. Also you'll have to then edit your `wp-config` to read from the correct database.

Answer (score 0):

To import your database,

- open it with your text editor like NotePad++
- locate (should be at the beginning of the file) and erase the line:
  "CREATE DATABASE yourdbname"
- Save it
- Now try to import it again

Also, it seems like you have only one database called Wordpress and you're using it for all your websites, right? You should make a unique name, for each database/site you create. You can still do that for your current site and create a new database, import your tables, and edit your wp-config.php file to communicate with the new database.

Comment: I took a closer look at my backup.sql file and there's a "CREATE DATABASE" line for each database I have! (I had 5 uniquely-named databases). I bet when I exported my backup, it was for all my locally-hosted databases and not just the single one I'm working on now.